# Too many output arguments error when using lsqcurvefit in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a set of 7 ordinary differential equations and 1 algebraic which I use to calculate the concentrations of 8 species with time. I have also conducted experiments to measure the concentrations of such 8 species. The challenge I have now that the concentrations predicted by the equations are not the same as the concentrations measured during experiments. As a result, I am looking at ways the regress the 4 parameters and 8 initial conditions, such that the calculated concentrations can match the experimental concentrations. I have found an example on the internet, from this link:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/329901-solving-coupled-differential-equations

in which the approach of using matlab's lsqcurvefit was followed. I Have tried to follow the step by step, however, I get the error message:

```
Error using EstimationOfParametersAndInitialConditionsUsingLSQCURVEFIT3/ode15ifun
Too many output arguments.

Error in lsqcurvefit (line 213)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Error in EstimationOfParametersAndInitialConditionsUsingLSQCURVEFIT3 (line 155)
B = lsqcurvefit(@ode15ifun, eqns0, ExperimentalTime, ExperimentalConcentrations)

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot continue.
```

My current code is:

```
function EstimationOfParametersAndInitialConditionsUsingLSQCURVEFIT3
global ExperimentalTime ExperimentalConcentrations
function ode15ifun
ExperimentalTime = [600
                    1200
                    1800
                    2400
                    3000
                    10200
                    17400
                    24600
                    31800
                    39000
                    46200
                    53400
                    60600
                    67800
                    75000
                    82200
                    89400
                    96600
                    103800
                    111000
                    118200
                    125400
                    132600
                    139800
                    147000
                    154200
                    161400
                    168600
                    175800
                    183000];
ExperimentalConcentrations = [  0.00E+00    6.97E-08    3.34E-01    4.88E-06    4.88E-06    4.86E+01    0.00E+00    7.41E-06
                                1.72E-02    8.76E-08    6.79E-01    4.88E-06    4.88E-06    4.92E+01    0.00E+00    9.33E-06
                                1.71E-02    1.18E-07    1.04E+00    5.11E-06    5.11E-06    4.94E+01    0.00E+00    1.20E-05
                                1.70E-02    1.03E-07    1.41E+00    5.11E-06    5.11E-06    4.96E+01    0.00E+00    1.05E-05
                                1.68E-02    1.77E-07    6.00E+00    5.35E-06    5.35E-06    3.78E+01    6.30E+00    1.74E-05
                                1.74E-02    3.65E-07    1.07E+01    5.35E-06    5.35E-06    3.09E+01    9.33E+00    3.72E-05
                                1.65E-02    3.50E-07    1.56E+01    5.36E-06    5.36E-06    2.67E+01    1.13E+01    3.55E-05
                                1.67E-02    8.83E-07    2.07E+01    5.36E-06    5.36E-06    1.98E+01    1.43E+01    1.00E-04
                                1.67E-02    5.01E-06    2.59E+01    5.07E-06    5.07E-06    1.14E+01    1.79E+01    4.07E-02
                                1.70E-02    5.06E-06    3.14E+01    5.07E-06    5.07E-06    9.58E+00    1.91E+01    2.45E-01
                                1.80E-02    4.93E-06    3.67E+01    4.93E-06    4.93E-06    5.65E+00    2.09E+01    6.17E-01
                                2.15E-02    5.29E-06    4.18E+01    5.30E-06    5.30E-06    3.32E+00    2.21E+01    1.32E+00
                                2.68E-02    5.30E-06    4.66E+01    5.30E-06    5.30E-06    0.00E+00    2.37E+01    2.29E+00
                                3.07E-02    5.30E-06    5.09E+01    5.30E-06    5.30E-06    0.00E+00    2.40E+01    2.34E+00
                                3.33E-02    9.45E-06    5.51E+01    9.46E-06    9.46E-06    0.00E+00    2.43E+01    2.40E+00
                                3.68E-02    9.45E-06    5.90E+01    9.46E-06    9.46E-06    0.00E+00    2.47E+01    1.82E+00
                                4.14E-02    1.13E-05    6.23E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.50E+01    1.38E+00
                                4.48E-02    1.15E-05    6.56E+01    1.15E-05    1.15E-05    0.00E+00    2.54E+01    2.09E+00
                                4.87E-02    1.10E-05    6.87E+01    1.10E-05    1.10E-05    0.00E+00    2.58E+01    1.82E+00
                                5.19E-02    1.10E-05    7.12E+01    1.10E-05    1.10E-05    0.00E+00    2.62E+01    1.58E+00
                                5.47E-02    1.04E-05    7.36E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.67E+01    2.29E+00
                                5.75E-02    1.04E-05    7.59E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.71E+01    1.62E+00
                                5.97E-02    1.04E-05    7.78E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.76E+01    1.12E+00
                                6.17E-02    1.03E-05    7.95E+01    1.03E-05    1.03E-05    0.00E+00    2.81E+01    8.91E-01
                                6.33E-02    1.04E-05    8.11E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.86E+01    8.51E-01
                                6.44E-02    1.05E-05    8.24E+01    1.06E-05    1.06E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    7.59E-01
                                6.48E-02    1.13E-05    8.24E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    8.71E-01
                                6.53E-02    1.13E-05    8.23E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    1.12E+00
                                6.57E-02    1.13E-05    8.21E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    1.00E+00
                                6.59E-02    1.03E-05    8.20E+01    1.03E-05    1.03E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    8.51E-01];

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 % b(1:4) = Parameters,  b(5:12) = Initial Conditions
 % MAPPING: b(1) = kga,  b(2) = kLa_SO2,  b(3) = ktot, b(4) = Kad, 
 %          b(5)= CSO2_gas(t0), b(6)= CCO2_gas(t0), b(7)= S_total(t0), b(8)= C_total(t0), b(9)= Ca2_total(t0),b(10)= CCaCO3(t0),b(11)= CCaSO3(t0),b(12)= CH(t0)   

syms  b V_Headspace F_rate CSO2_in CCO2_in R T HSO2 DCa2 DSO2 DHSO3 DSO32 kLa_CO2 HCO2 DCO2 DHCO3 DCO32 KSPCaSO3 BETCaSO3 BETCaCO3 MWCaCO3 KCO2 KHCO3 KSO2 KHSO3 Kw CCa2

eqn1 = diff(b(5),t)== F_rate/ V_Headspace * ( CSO2_in -  b(5)) - (b(5) * R * T - HSO2 * ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / ((1/b(1)) + 1/(b(2) * (((DSO2 * (HSO2 * b(5) * R * T - ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) + DHSO3 * (((KSO2 * HSO2 *  b(5) * R * T / b(12)) - ((b(7) * KSO2 * b(12))/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))) + DSO32 * ((((KSO2 * KHSO3 * HSO2 * b(5) * R * T/b(12)^2) - ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * b(5) * R * T - ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))));

eqn2 = diff(b(6) ,t)== F_rate/ V_Headspace * ( CCO2_in -  b(6)) - (kLa_CO2 * ((((DCO2*(HCO2 * b(6) * R * T - ((b(8) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3))) + DHCO3*(((KCO2 * HCO2 *  b(6) * R * T/b(12)) - ((C_total (t) * KCO2 * b(12))/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))) + DCO32 * ((((KCO2 * KHCO3 * HCO2 * b(6) * R * T/b(12)^2) - ((b(8) * KCO2 * KHCO3)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))))) / (DCO2 * (HCO2 * b(6) * R * T - ((C_total (t) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))))))*(b(6) * R * T/HCO2 - ((b(8) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3))));

eqn3 = diff(b(7),t)== (b(5) * R * T - HSO2*((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / ((1/b(1)) + 1/(b(2) * (((DSO2*(HSO2* b(5) * R * T - ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) + DHSO3*(((KSO2 * HSO2 *  b(5) * R * T/b(12)) - ((b(7) * KSO2 * b(12))/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))) + DSO32 * ((((KSO2 * KHSO3 *HSO2* b(5) * R * T/b(12)^2) - ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * b(5) * R * T - ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))) - 0.162 * exp(-5153/T) * (((CCa2 * ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / KSPCaSO3) - 1)^2 * (BETCaSO3/((CCa2 * (((((KSO2 * KHSO3 *HSO2* b(5) * R * T/b(12)^2) - ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * b(5) * R * T - ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))))/ KSPCaSO3;

eqn4 = diff(b(8),t)== (kLa_CO2 * ((((DCO2*(HCO2 * b(6) * R * T - ((b(8) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3))) + DHCO3*(((KCO2 * HCO2 *  b(6) * R * T/b(12)) - ((C_total (t) * KCO2 * b(12))/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))) + DCO32 * ((((KCO2 * KHCO3 * HCO2 * b(6) * R * T/b(12)^2) - ((b(8) * KCO2 * KHCO3)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))))) / (DCO2 * (HCO2 * b(6) * R * T - ((C_total (t) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))))))*(b(6) * R * T /HCO2 - ((b(8) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3))))  + (b(3) * BETCaCO3 * MWCaCO3 * b(10) * b(12) *(1 - (b(4) * b(12))/(1 + b(4) * b(12))));

eqn5 = diff(b(9),t)== (-1) * (b(3) * BETCaCO3 * MWCaCO3 * b(10) * b(12) *(1 - (b(4) * b(12))/(1 + b(4) * b(12)))) - (0.162 * exp(-5153/T) * (((CCa2 * ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / KSPCaSO3) - 1)^2 * (BETCaSO3/((CCa2 * (((((KSO2 * KHSO3 *HSO2* b(5) * R * T/b(12)^2) - ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * b(5) * R * T - ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))))/ KSPCaSO3;

eqn6 = diff(b(10),t)== (-1) * (b(3) * BETCaCO3 * MWCaCO3 * b(10) * b(12) * (1 - (b(4) * b(12))/(1 + b(4) * b(12))));

eqn7 = diff(b(11),t)== 0.162 * exp(-5153/T) * ((((CCa2 * ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / KSPCaSO3) - 1)^2 * (BETCaSO3/((CCa2 * (((((KSO2 * KHSO3 *HSO2* b(5) * R * T/b(12)^2) - ((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * b(5) * R * T - ((b(7) * b(12)^2)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))))/ KSPCaSO3;

eqn8 = diff(b(12),t)== b(12) + 2 * CCa2 - ((b(7) *KSO2 * b(12))/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3))-  2*((b(7) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(b(12)^2 + KSO2 * b(12) + KSO2 * KHSO3)) - ((b(8) * KCO2 * b(12))/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3)) - 2 * ((b(8) * KCO2 * KHCO3)/(b(12)^2 + KCO2 * b(12) + KCO2 * KHCO3))- Kw / b(12);

eqns = [eqn1 eqn2 eqn3 eqn4 eqn5 eqn6 eqn7 eqn8];

vars = [b(5); b(6); b(7); b(8); b(9); b(10); b(11); b(12)];

origVars = length(vars);

M = incidenceMatrix(eqns, vars);

[eqns, vars] = reduceDifferentialOrder(eqns, vars);

isLowIndexDAE(eqns,vars);

f = daeFunction(eqns,vars, V_Headspace, F_rate, CSO2_in, CCO2_in, CCa2, R, T, HSO2, b(1), DCa2, DSO2, DHSO3, DSO32, b(2), kLa_CO2, HCO2, DCO2, DHCO3, DCO32, KSPCaSO3, BETCaSO3, b(3), BETCaCO3, MWCaCO3, b(4), KCO2, KHCO3, KSO2, KHSO3, Kw);

V_Headspace = 1.5e-6;       
F_rate      = 1.66667e-5;    
CSO2_in     = 6.51332e-2;   
CCO2_in     = 0;            
CCa2        = 10;           
R           = 8.314;        
T           = 323.15;       
HSO2        = 149;                                              
b(1)        = 4.14e-6;                                          
DCa2        = 1.39e-9;                                          
DSO2        = 2.89e-9;                                    
DHSO3       = 2.89e-9;                                     
DSO32       = 2.89e-9;                                    
b(2)        = 8.4e-4;                                           
kLa_CO2     = 9.598e-4;                                         
HCO2        = 5.15e3;                                           
DCO2        = 3.53e-9;                                    
DHCO3       = 2.89e-9;                                    
DCO32       = 2.89e-9;                                    
KSPCaSO3    = 1.07e-7;                                          
BETCaSO3    = 10;                                              
b(3)        = 8.825e-3;                                         
BETCaCO3    = 12.54;                                            
MWCaCO3     = 100.0869;                                         
b(4)         = 0.84;                                             
KCO2        = 1.7e-3;                                           
KHCO3       = 6.55e-8;                                          
KSO2        = 6.24;                                             
KHSO3       = 5.68e-5;                                          
Kw          = 5.3e-8;                                          

F = @(t, Y, YP) f(t, Y, YP, V_Headspace, F_rate, CSO2_in, CCO2_in, CCa2, R, T, HSO2, b(1), DCa2, DSO2, DHSO3, DSO32, b(2), kLa_CO2, HCO2, DCO2, DHSO3, DSO32, KSPCaSO3, BETCaSO3, b(3), BETCaCO3, MWCaCO3, b(4), KCO2, KHCO3, KSO2, KHSO3, Kw);

vars;                                   

%b0est = [0; 0; 3.3351e-1; 4.879e-6; 4.879e-6; 4.862e+1; 0; 7.413e-6];
 b0est = [1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;];                                   
  bp0est = zeros(8,1);                                  
 opt = odeset('RelTol', 10.0^(-7), 'AbsTol' , 10.0^(-7));                                   
 [b0, bp0] = decic(F, 0, b(5:12), [], bp0est, [], opt);                                   
 [tSol,eqns] = ode15i(F, ExperimentalTime, b0, bp0, opt);                                   
 for k = 1:origVars                                   
 S{k} = char(vars(k));                                  
 end                                      

end


eqns0 = [4.14e-6;  8.4e-4;  8.825e-3;  0.84; 0; 0; 3.3351e-1; 4.879e-6; 4.879e-6; 4.862e+1; 0; 7.413e-6];

%B = lsqcurvefit(@ode15ifun, eqns0, ExperimentalTime, ExperimentalConcentrations, zeros(size(eqns0)), inf(size(eqns0)))

B = lsqcurvefit(@ode15ifun, eqns0, ExperimentalTime, ExperimentalConcentrations)

fprintf(1, '\n\tParameters:\n\t\tkga = %11.3E\n\t\tkLa = %11.3E\n\t\tktot = %11.3E\n\t\tKad = %11.3E\n\tInitial Conditions:\n\t\tCSO2gas = %11.3E\n\t\tCCO2gas = %11.3E\n\t\tStotal = %11.3E\n\t\tCtotal = %11.3E\n\t\tCatotal = %11.3E\n\t\tCCaCO3 = %11.3E\n\t\tCCaSO3 = %11.3E\n\t\tCH = %11.3E\n', B);

F = @(t, B, BP) f(t, B, BP, V_Headspace, F_rate, CSO2_in, CCO2_in, CCa2, R, T, HSO2, DCa2, DSO2, DHSO3, DSO32, kLa_CO2, HCO2, DCO2, DHSO3, DSO32, KSPCaSO3, BETCaSO3, BETCaCO3, MWCaCO3, KCO2, KHCO3, KSO2, KHSO3, Kw);

[tSol,eqns] = ode15i(F, ExperimentalTime, B(5:12), bp0, opt);

figure(2)
plot(ExperimentalTime, ExperimentalConcentrations, 'p')
hold on
plot(tSol, ySol, '--')
hold off
grid
legend('Exp-SO_{2-gas}','Exp-CO_{2-gas}','Exp-S_{total}','Exp-C_{total}','Exp-Ca^{2+}_{total}','Exp-CaCO_{3}','Exp-CaSO_{3}.^{1}/_{2}H_{2}O','Exp-H^{+}', 'Mod-SO_{2-gas}','Mod-CO_{2-gas}','Mod-S_{total}','Mod-C_{total}','Mod-Ca^{2+}_{total}','Mod-CaCO_{3}','Mod-CaSO_{3}.^{1}/_{2}H_{2}O','Mod-H^{+}', 'Location','best')

end
```

I can not spot where I am going wrong. I do not know where to fix. What can I try?

When I run the code without including the lsqcurvefit, the code does not give errors, however, the experimental results does not match the calculated values. I think that when I regress 4 input values, the calculated values will fit the experimental values. Below is the code on which I have commented-out the lsqcurvefit:

```
%function EstimationOfParametersAndInitialConditionsUsingLSQCURVEFIT2
function ode15ifun
ExperimentalTime = [600
                    1200
                    1800
                    2400
                    3000
                    10200
                    17400
                    24600
                    31800
                    39000
                    46200
                    53400
                    60600
                    67800
                    75000
                    82200
                    89400
                    96600
                    103800
                    111000
                    118200
                    125400
                    132600
                    139800
                    147000
                    154200
                    161400
                    168600
                    175800
                    183000];
ExperimentalConcentrations = [  0.00E+00    6.97E-08    3.34E-01    4.88E-06    4.88E-06    4.86E+01    0.00E+00    7.41E-06
                                1.72E-02    8.76E-08    6.79E-01    4.88E-06    4.88E-06    4.92E+01    0.00E+00    9.33E-06
                                1.71E-02    1.18E-07    1.04E+00    5.11E-06    5.11E-06    4.94E+01    0.00E+00    1.20E-05
                                1.70E-02    1.03E-07    1.41E+00    5.11E-06    5.11E-06    4.96E+01    0.00E+00    1.05E-05
                                1.68E-02    1.77E-07    6.00E+00    5.35E-06    5.35E-06    3.78E+01    6.30E+00    1.74E-05
                                1.74E-02    3.65E-07    1.07E+01    5.35E-06    5.35E-06    3.09E+01    9.33E+00    3.72E-05
                                1.65E-02    3.50E-07    1.56E+01    5.36E-06    5.36E-06    2.67E+01    1.13E+01    3.55E-05
                                1.67E-02    8.83E-07    2.07E+01    5.36E-06    5.36E-06    1.98E+01    1.43E+01    1.00E-04
                                1.67E-02    5.01E-06    2.59E+01    5.07E-06    5.07E-06    1.14E+01    1.79E+01    4.07E-02
                                1.70E-02    5.06E-06    3.14E+01    5.07E-06    5.07E-06    9.58E+00    1.91E+01    2.45E-01
                                1.80E-02    4.93E-06    3.67E+01    4.93E-06    4.93E-06    5.65E+00    2.09E+01    6.17E-01
                                2.15E-02    5.29E-06    4.18E+01    5.30E-06    5.30E-06    3.32E+00    2.21E+01    1.32E+00
                                2.68E-02    5.30E-06    4.66E+01    5.30E-06    5.30E-06    0.00E+00    2.37E+01    2.29E+00
                                3.07E-02    5.30E-06    5.09E+01    5.30E-06    5.30E-06    0.00E+00    2.40E+01    2.34E+00
                                3.33E-02    9.45E-06    5.51E+01    9.46E-06    9.46E-06    0.00E+00    2.43E+01    2.40E+00
                                3.68E-02    9.45E-06    5.90E+01    9.46E-06    9.46E-06    0.00E+00    2.47E+01    1.82E+00
                                4.14E-02    1.13E-05    6.23E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.50E+01    1.38E+00
                                4.48E-02    1.15E-05    6.56E+01    1.15E-05    1.15E-05    0.00E+00    2.54E+01    2.09E+00
                                4.87E-02    1.10E-05    6.87E+01    1.10E-05    1.10E-05    0.00E+00    2.58E+01    1.82E+00
                                5.19E-02    1.10E-05    7.12E+01    1.10E-05    1.10E-05    0.00E+00    2.62E+01    1.58E+00
                                5.47E-02    1.04E-05    7.36E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.67E+01    2.29E+00
                                5.75E-02    1.04E-05    7.59E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.71E+01    1.62E+00
                                5.97E-02    1.04E-05    7.78E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.76E+01    1.12E+00
                                6.17E-02    1.03E-05    7.95E+01    1.03E-05    1.03E-05    0.00E+00    2.81E+01    8.91E-01
                                6.33E-02    1.04E-05    8.11E+01    1.04E-05    1.04E-05    0.00E+00    2.86E+01    8.51E-01
                                6.44E-02    1.05E-05    8.24E+01    1.06E-05    1.06E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    7.59E-01
                                6.48E-02    1.13E-05    8.24E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    8.71E-01
                                6.53E-02    1.13E-05    8.23E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    1.12E+00
                                6.57E-02    1.13E-05    8.21E+01    1.13E-05    1.13E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    1.00E+00
                                6.59E-02    1.03E-05    8.20E+01    1.03E-05    1.03E-05    0.00E+00    2.90E+01    8.51E-01];

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



syms  CSO2_gas(t) CCO2_gas(t) S_total(t) C_total(t) Ca2_total(t) CCaCO3(t) CCaSO3(t) CH(t) V_Headspace F_rate CSO2_in CCO2_in R T HSO2 kga DCa2 DSO2 DHSO3 DSO32 kLa_SO2 kLa_CO2 HCO2 DCO2 DHCO3 DCO32 KSPCaSO3 BETCaSO3 ktot BETCaCO3 MWCaCO3 Kad KCO2 KHCO3 KSO2 KHSO3 Kw CCa2


eqn1 = diff(CSO2_gas(t),t)== (F_rate/ V_Headspace) * ( CSO2_in -  CSO2_gas(t)) - (( CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - HSO2 * ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / ((1/kga) + 1/( kLa_SO2 * ((( DSO2 * (HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) + DHSO3 * (((KSO2 * HSO2 *  CSO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)) - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * CH(t))/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))) + DSO32 * (((( KSO2 * KHSO3 * HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)^2) - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / ( DSO2 * ( HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))))));

eqn2 = diff(CCO2_gas(t) ,t)== (F_rate/ V_Headspace) * ( CCO2_in -  CCO2_gas(t)) - ( kLa_CO2 * ((((DCO2 * (HCO2 * CCO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((C_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3))) + DHCO3 * (((KCO2 * HCO2 *  CCO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)) - ((C_total (t) * KCO2 * CH(t))/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2*KHCO3)))) + DCO32 * ((((KCO2 * KHCO3 * HCO2 * CCO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)^2) - ((C_total(t) * KCO2 * KHCO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))))) / (DCO2 * (HCO2 * CCO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((C_total (t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3))))))) * (CCO2_gas(t) * R * T / HCO2 - (( C_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3))));

eqn3 = diff(S_total(t),t)== (( CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - HSO2 * ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / ((1/kga) + 1/(kLa_SO2 * ((( DSO2 * (HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) + DHSO3 * ((( KSO2 * HSO2 *  CSO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)) - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * CH(t))/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))) + DSO32 * (((( KSO2 * KHSO3 * HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)^2) - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / ( DSO2 * ( HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - (( S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))))) - ( 0.162 * exp(-5153 / T) * ((( CCa2 * ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / KSPCaSO3) - 1)^2 * (BETCaSO3/((CCa2 * ((((( KSO2 * KHSO3 * HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)^2) - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))))/ KSPCaSO3);

eqn4 = diff(C_total(t),t)== ( kLa_CO2 * ((((DCO2 * ( HCO2 * CCO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((C_total(t) * CH(t)^2) / (CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3))) + DHCO3 * (((KCO2 * HCO2 *  CCO2_gas(t) * R * T / CH(t)) - ((C_total (t) * KCO2 * CH(t))/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))) + DCO32 * ((((KCO2 * KHCO3 * HCO2 * CCO2_gas(t) * R * T / CH(t)^2) - (( C_total(t) * KCO2 * KHCO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3)))))) / ( DCO2 * (HCO2 * CCO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((C_total (t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3))))))) * (CCO2_gas(t) * R * T / HCO2 - ((C_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3))))  + (ktot * BETCaCO3 * MWCaCO3 * CCaCO3(t) * CH(t) *(1 - (Kad * CH(t))/(1 + Kad * CH(t))));

eqn5 = diff(Ca2_total(t),t)== (-1) * ( ktot * BETCaCO3 * MWCaCO3 * CCaCO3(t) * CH(t) * (1 - (Kad * CH(t))/(1 + Kad * CH(t)))) - (0.162 * exp(-5153 / T) * ((( CCa2 * ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / KSPCaSO3) - 1)^2 * (BETCaSO3/((CCa2 * (((((KSO2 * KHSO3 * HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)^2) - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2*KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))))/ KSPCaSO3;

eqn6 = diff(CCaCO3(t),t)== (-1) * (ktot * BETCaCO3 * MWCaCO3 * CCaCO3(t) * CH(t) * (1 - (Kad * CH(t)) / (1 + Kad * CH(t))));

eqn7 = diff(CCaSO3(t),t)== 0.162 * exp(-5153 / T) * ((((CCa2 * ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))) / KSPCaSO3) - 1)^2 * (BETCaSO3 / ((CCa2 * (((((KSO2 * KHSO3 * HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T/CH(t)^2) - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3) / (CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)))))) / (DSO2 * (HSO2 * CSO2_gas(t) * R * T - ((S_total(t) * CH(t)^2)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3))))))))/ KSPCaSO3;

eqn8 = diff(CH(t),t)== CH(t) + 2 * CCa2 - ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * CH(t)) / (CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)) -  2 * ((S_total(t) * KSO2 * KHSO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KSO2 * CH(t) + KSO2 * KHSO3)) - ((C_total(t) * KCO2 * CH(t))/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3)) - 2 * ((C_total(t) * KCO2 * KHCO3)/(CH(t)^2 + KCO2 * CH(t) + KCO2 * KHCO3))- Kw / CH(t);

eqns = [eqn1 eqn2 eqn3 eqn4 eqn5 eqn6 eqn7 eqn8];

vars = [CSO2_gas(t); CCO2_gas(t); S_total(t); C_total(t); Ca2_total(t); CCaCO3(t); CCaSO3(t); CH(t)];

origVars = length(vars);

M = incidenceMatrix(eqns, vars);

[eqns, vars] = reduceDifferentialOrder(eqns, vars);

isLowIndexDAE(eqns,vars);

f = daeFunction(eqns,vars, V_Headspace, F_rate, CSO2_in, CCO2_in, CCa2, R, T, HSO2, kga, DCa2, DSO2, DHSO3, DSO32, kLa_SO2, kLa_CO2, HCO2, DCO2, DHCO3, DCO32, KSPCaSO3, BETCaSO3, ktot, BETCaCO3, MWCaCO3, Kad, KCO2, KHCO3, KSO2, KHSO3, Kw);

V_Headspace = 1.5e-6;       
F_rate      = 1.66667e-5;    
CSO2_in     = 6.51332e-2;   
CCO2_in     = 0;            
CCa2        = 10;           
R           = 8.314;        
T           = 323.15;       
HSO2        = 149;          
kga         = 4.14e-6;      
DCa2        = 1.39e-9;      
DSO2        = 2.89e-9;
DHSO3       = 2.89e-9; 
DSO32       = 2.89e-9;
kLa_SO2     = 8.4e-4;       
kLa_CO2     = 9.598e-4;     
HCO2        = 5.15e3;       
DCO2        = 3.53e-9;
DHCO3       = 2.89e-9;
DCO32       = 2.89e-9;
KSPCaSO3    = 1.07e-7;      
BETCaSO3    = 10;           
ktot        = 8.825e-3;     
BETCaCO3    = 12.54;        
MWCaCO3     = 100.0869;     
Kad         = 0.84;         
KCO2        = 1.7e-3;       
KHCO3       = 6.55e-8;      
KSO2        = 6.24;         
KHSO3       = 5.68e-5;      
Kw          = 5.3e-8;      

F = @(t, Y, YP) f(t, Y, YP, V_Headspace, F_rate, CSO2_in, CCO2_in, CCa2, R, T, HSO2, kga, DCa2, DSO2, DHSO3, DSO32, kLa_SO2, kLa_CO2, HCO2, DCO2, DHSO3, DSO32, KSPCaSO3, BETCaSO3, ktot, BETCaCO3, MWCaCO3, Kad, KCO2, KHCO3, KSO2, KHSO3, Kw);

vars;

y0est = [0; 0; 3.3351e-1; 4.879e-6; 4.879e-6; 4.862e+1; 0; 7.413e-6];
yp0est = zeros(8,1);
opt = odeset('RelTol', 10.0^(-7), 'AbsTol' , 10.0^(-7));
[y0, yp0] = decic(F, 0, y0est, [], yp0est, [], opt);
[tSol,ySol] = ode15i(F, [600, 183000], y0, yp0, opt);
for k = 1:origVars
  S{k} = char(vars(k));
end

figure(1)
plot(tSol,ySol)
hold on
plot(ExperimentalTime, ExperimentalConcentrations, 'p')
legend('Exp-SO_{2-gas}','Exp-CO_{2-gas}','Exp-S_{total}','Exp-C_{total}','Exp-Ca^{2+}_{total}','Exp-CaCO_{3}','Exp-CaSO_{3}.^{1}/_{2}H_{2}O','Exp-H^{+}', 'Mod-SO_{2-gas}','Mod-CO_{2-gas}','Mod-S_{total}','Mod-C_{total}','Mod-Ca^{2+}_{total}','Mod-CaCO_{3}','Mod-CaSO_{3}.^{1}/_{2}H_{2}O','Mod-H^{+}', 'Location','best')
hold off
end

%eqns0 = [4.14e-6;  8.4e-4;  8.825e-3;  0.84; 0; 0; 3.3351e-1; 4.879e-6; 4.879e-6; 4.862e+1; 0; 7.413e-6];
```

%B = lsqcurvefit(@ode15ifun, eqns0, ExperimentalTime, ExperimentalConcentrations, zeros(size(eqns0)), inf(size(eqns0)))

%F = @(t, Y, YP) f(t, B, BP, V_Headspace, F_rate, CSO2_in, CCO2_in, CCa2, R, T, HSO2, B(1), DCa2, DSO2, DHSO3, DSO32, B(2), kLa_CO2, HCO2, DCO2, DHSO3, DSO32, KSPCaSO3, BETCaSO3, B(3), BETCaCO3, MWCaCO3, B(4), KCO2, KHCO3, KSO2, KHSO3, Kw);

%[tSol,eqns] = ode15i(F, ExperimentalTime, B(5:12), bp0, opt);

Comment: Your function `ode15ifun` doesn't appear to return anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Bungo. Are you reffering to the ode15i nested in the first code or in the second code? I am using MATLAB R2018a, when, I run the second code I get this figure:

Comment: Well, both versions don't return anything. Doesn't `lsqcurvefit` expect you to provide a function that returns a value?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Bungo. Are you reffering to the ode15i nested in the first code or in the second code? I am using MATLAB R2018a, when, I run the second code I get this figure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud16lpsk2xkykkg/Figure1.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I am new on matlab, I think lsqcurvefit expect me to provide a function that return a value, but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: Can I please ask you to help.

Comment: If `ode15ifun` is going to return a value, it should start like this: `function [retval] = ode15ifun`. Then somewhere in the function body you need to assign a value to `retval`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I try that straight-away.

Comment: When I change line 3 to:  function [retval] = ode15ifun; and line 137 to retval = [b]; I get the following error: Error using EstimationOfParametersAndInitialConditionsUsingLSQCURVEFIT3/ode15ifun
Too many input arguments.

Error in lsqcurvefit (line 213)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Error in EstimationOfParametersAndInitialConditionsUsingLSQCURVEFIT3 (line 155)
B = lsqcurvefit(@ode15ifun, eqns0, ExperimentalTime, ExperimentalConcentrations)

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot continue